# Susy Grids: change the size of 12-column div without changing the overall grid size?

Tags: css, layout, grid, width, susy-compass

I am using Suzy for partial re-design of an existing website. In stage 1, I am designing the top part of the page: header, etc. and using the legacy code for the rest.

At this point I need to fit the new headers to the old page content. Unfortunately, the usable space I end up with is smaller than the width of the existing content.

Any idea on how to adjust the content space (the width available for content placed inside the container) of `#legacy-content-wrapper` to be 1002px wide?

Here's my code:

```
$total-columns  : 12;             // a 12-column grid
$column-width   : 69px;           
$gutter-width   : 14px;           
$grid-padding   : 25px;            
$container-style: static;
// the resulting grid is 1032px wide

#header-wrapper {
  @include container;  
  .some-header-content { @include span-columns(3,12); }
  .some-other-header-content { @include span-columns(9 omega,12); }  
}

#page-wrapper {
  @include container;

  // legacy item, needs to be 1002px wide!
  #legacy-content-wrapper {

      @include span-columns(12 omega, 12);

      // my children will be 982px at 100% width

      // @include bleed($gutter-width) changes the width of the container
      // but does not change the size of the usable space within it.

      // how can I modify this item to have content swidth of 1002px?

  }
}
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="legacy-content-wrapper">
        <div>I'd like to be 1002 pixels wide!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I ended up with:**

```
#legacy-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 0 -$grid-padding;
  padding: 22px 14px;
  @include clearfix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust any of the grid settings to fit within the required space. Probably the most straightforward way to trim 30px off your grid size would be from the `grid-padding` setting.

```
$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 69px;           
$gutter-width   : 14px;           
$grid-padding   : 10px;            
$container-style: static;
```

You could alternatively tweak the `column-width` or `gutter-width` settings to achieve the same number. It's hard to say the best approach without seeing the design. Either way should get you to 1002px.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I needed to change only this container without touching the overall grid, so I added the custom CSS described above.